# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0

Tags: android, dependency-management

This code shows retrofit dependency error, I am currently using **Android Studio 3.5.2**. Please help me to resolve this dependency

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blog"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:convertor-gson:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with latest version of retrofit as below.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
```

Comment: 2.6.2 actually ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell Gradle they are dependencies.

```
dependencies 
{ 
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:convertor-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

Latest Retrofit2 is also `2.6.2`.